# Observer Pattern not working on Ruby

Tags: ruby, observer-pattern

I implemented this example below for use of the Observer Pattern on Ruby. I tried follow [this](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html#method-i-notify_observers), but didn't work.

```
require "observer"

class AAnyClass
  extend Observable
  changed
  notify_observers self
end

module AnObserver

  extend self

  def update constant
    p "Constant #{constant} has been called."
  end

  def observe constant
    constant.add_observer(self)
  end

end

AnObserver.observe AAnyClass
# must return "Constant AAnyClass has been called."
AAnyClass
# must return "Constant AAnyClass has been called."
AAnyClass
```

**UPDATE**

I converted the module `AnObserver` into a class, like this:

```
class AnObserver

  def update constant
    $stdout.puts "Constant #{constant} has been called."
  end

end
```

And change the class `AAnyClass` adding the `Observable` methods into a constructor and passing `AnObserver` instance as parameter to method `add_observer`, like this:

```
class AAnyClass
  include Observable

  def initialize
    add_observer AnObserver.new
    changed
    notify_observers AAnyClass
  end

end
```

And, finally, I added a little code that modifies the `eigenclass` of `AAnyClass` with the same code of the `AAnyClass’s` constructor.

```
class << AAnyClass
  extend Observable

  add_observer AnObserver.new
  changed
  notify_observers AAnyClass
end
AAnyClass

AAnyClass.new
AAnyClass.new
```

That’s it.

Comment: Your code calls `notify_observers` once, during parsing stage (when class is declared.) Pattern can’t work/do not work. Code can.

Comment: There is some way for I know that "AAnyClass" was called? How the ```included``` method of ```Module```.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using modules and "extends" where you should be using classes and "includes". Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
require "observer"

class AAnyClass
  include Observable

  def run
    changed
    notify_observers(self)
  end
end

class AnObserver

  def initialize(ob)
    ob.add_observer(self)
  end

  def update constant
    p "Constant #{constant} has been called."
  end

  def observe constant
    constant.add_observer(constant)
  end

end

ob = AAnyClass.new
AnObserver.new ob
ob.run
```

Comment: I added a update in the post. But I based on what you did.